# error unary minus operator applied to unsigned type results in unsigned

Tags: c++, c++11, unsigned, signed

I currently have a function in my code that converts numeric types to strings.Due to reasons I did not use `std::to_string`. Now this code build fine on XCode but window seems to be complaining. The reason windows is complaining is because at one point I am passing an unsigned type and then doing a negative on it still keeps it positive as the type is unsigned.  My question is can I put an if class to check if the type is signed and then enter the condition ? Will that fix the problem

```
    template<typename t>
    std::string MyFunct(t num,int base=10)
    {
        char str [sizeof(t)*8+1];
        int i = 0;
        bool isNegative = false;


        if (num == 0)
        {
            str[i++] = '0';
            str[i] = '\0';
            return str;
        }

        //Negative only when base is 10
        if (num < 0 && base == 10)
        {
            isNegative = true;
            num = -num; //<------ERROR in case the type is unsigned
        }
        ....
        ....
    }
```

How can i fix this ? Is there a way for me to tell the compiler only if the type is unsigned go in here?

Comment: Well, you could try something like `num = num * (1 -
 2 * std::is_unsigned<T>::value)`. Don't know, however, whether it does what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JohnB what would `std::is_unsigned<T>::value` output  if its unsigned?

Comment: `true`, I guess. Probably `num = num * (1 - (std::is_unsigned<T>::value ? 2 : 0) )` is the correct approach.

Comment: Can't you simply write `num = (T) (-1) * num;` ?

Comment: I agree this would work. Can you put that as a solution

Comment: I am trying the second approach can you put both as the answer

Comment: Please disable this dumb warning and sign the petition to get Microsoft to remove it permanently.

Comment: If you know integers are 2s complement, you can replace -num with ~num+1. But I think this warning is silly and should be ignored, since the block of code cannot be executed unless num is less than 0, which is impossible for an unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

With a modern compiler that supports C++17, [one could use `constexpr if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) together with [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to execute the negation only for signed integer types. Note that an ordinary `if` is still likely to result in the diagnostic from your compiler, `constexpr if` is required.

An alternative to `constexpr if` is a fairly straightforward template specialization:

```
template<typename t, bool is_signed=std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed>
    std::string MyFunct(t num,int base=10);

template<typename t>
std::string MyFunct<t, true>(t num,int base10)
{
    // The signed specialization of MyFunct()
}

template<typename t>
std::string MyFunct<t, false>(t num,int base)
{
    // The unsigned specialization of MyFunct()
}
```

Only the signed version of your conversion function would use the negation logic. Of course, both the signed and the unsigned version of your function would have a lot of code in common; but this now becomes an ordinary situation with simple, straightforward refactoring.

Comment: How about `num = num * (1 - 2 * std::is_unsigned<T>::value)`? as @JohnB suggested ? I would like to know what `std::is_unsigned<T>::value` returns if the type is signed and if its unsigned ?

Comment: Was your Google broken, for the last two hours, so you couldn't look up what `std::is_unsigned<T>::value` returns?